# Migrate WSO2API manager from H2 to Mysql

Tags: mysql, h2, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have a running WSO2API manager. How can I migrate the existing API Manager using H2 inbuilt support to MYSQL server?

What are the steps that I need to perform for migrating this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the first step you will have to export your existing data in H2 database to MYSQL database. To do so you can use a tool like [DBCopy Plugin for SQuirreL SQL Client](http://dbcopyplugin.sourceforge.net/) .

Then, you will have to point API manager to use MYSQL database instead of built it H2 database. To change the database, open /repository/conf/datasources/master-datasources.xml. In this file you will see URLs pointing to internal databses in H2 server, now you need to change them to point to databases in MYSQL server by placing the URL of your MYSQL server database.

Comment: I have already set up API Manager with MYSQL and it's running. now I have to take a dump from H2 and source it to mysql.

Comment: For that you will have to use a tool like  DBCopy Plugin for SQuirreL SQL Client